# Can't generate QueryDsl

Tags: xml, maven, querydsl

I modified my project acording to the article [Spring Data JPA Tutorial: Using Querydsl in a Multi-module Maven Project](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-using-querydsl-in-a-multi-module-maven-project/) and still I can't generate any Query classes.

I added to my root `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in my model `pom.xml` i added `<build>` section:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I tried build by `man clean install` and `man apt:process` on root `pom.xml` and model `pom.xml` but without results. In `target/generated-sources` I have only empty directory named `annotations`. Im not getting any errors during maven build.

Comment: What do you mean by `without results`? Did you check `target/generated-sources` directory?

Comment: yes, on every try I was checking the `target/generated-sources` directory, and there only emty directory named `annotations`

Comment: Remove the pluginManagement-tags and try again.

Comment: Didn't notice `<pluginManagement>` tag. Removing it would do the trick

Comment: @JoachimRohde please post this as an answer, that was it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the pluginManagement-tags and try again.